# How i can split Data from String with Unicode?

Tags: c#, unicode-string, converters

Good morning,
I have a question.
I need to recover Data from a String with Unicode for example

> "\u001f\u0001\u0013FERREIRA RAMOS MUZI\u001f\u0002\0\u001f\u0003\aRICARDO\u001f\u0004\u0003URY\u001f\u0005\b09031979\u001f\u0006\u000eMONTEVIDEO/URY\u001f\a\b34946682\u001f\b\u0004\"\a \u0016\u001f\t\b22072026\u001f\n\0"

The String in Bytes

```
1F011346455252454952412052414D4F53204D555A491F02001F03075249434152444F1F04035552591F050830393033313937391F060E4D4F4E5445564944454F2F5552591F070833343934363638321F0804220720161F090832323037323032361F0A00
```

I need to recover Name, LastName etc in an ArrayList or Arraystring, for example

> string[] array = {"Stephen", "King","11301958","NewYork/Usa"}

My problem if i use

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ByteArray);
```

to Get Data, i only get Name and Last Name, no Dates or where from.

How i can get that from this string?

Comment: `1F 01 13FERREIRA RAMOS MUZI`; `1F` field start, `01` field index, `13` length in bytes (19). This is much better processed as a byte array than as a string. This is a custom binary format; where are you getting it from and does it have documentation with some recommended way of processing it?

Comment: I has add a byte string

Comment: The problem is that some fields aren't strings and even the fields that are strings aren't always clear in their purpose. Field 8 contains `0x22072016`, which appears to a BCD encoding of similar data to what's encoded as a string in field 9 (`22072026`). To properly decode this, you need to know what all those fields *mean*. Of course you can guess, but this doesn't look like the kind of data where you're supposed to guess.

Comment: It is not Unicode, use BinaryReader to read this data.  There are 10 fields, each field starts with 0x1f.  The second byte is the field number (0x01..0A).  The third byte is the data length, followed by the data bytes.  Fields 2 and 10 are empty, field 8 is a pretty wonky one that *resembles* a date (22072016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

Detect only Letters a-zA-Z and Numbers with Regular Expression
If regular expresion fail or is a white Space, a Word is Complet and next add it to a List, 
at the end i have a List With all words and numbers necessary.

1- Convert Byte[] Data to string

```
// Convert utf-8 bytes to a string.
s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(apduRsp.Data);

List<string> test = new List<string>();
if (s_unicode2.Length > 0)
{
   test = GetWords(s_unicode2);
}
```

2- Call GetWords() with string converted from Byte[]

```
private List<string> GetWords(string text)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
        string Word = "";
        char[] ca = text.ToCharArray();
        List<string> characters = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ca.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = ca[i];
            if (c > 65535)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (char.IsHighSurrogate(c))
            {
                i++;
                characters.Add(new string(new[] { c, ca[i] }));
            }
            else
            {
                if (reg.Match(c.ToString()).Success || c.ToString() == "/")
                {
                    Word = Word + c.ToString();
                    //characters.Add(new string(new[] { c }));
                }
                else if(c.ToString() == " ")
                {
                    if(Word.Length > 0)
                        characters.Add(Word);
                    Word = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Word.Length > 0)
                        characters.Add(Word);
                    Word = "";
                }

            }

        }
        return characters;
    }
```

3- Result from GetWords()

[image: List<string> values returned]

That solution for me at the moment is good, but some people have 2 names, and this is a little problem at the moment of showing.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to create a custom parser:

```
byte [] bytes = // Your data here....
// Parser
List<string> words = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) {
    if (0x1F == bytes[i]) {
        int index = bytes[i+1]; // Ignoring this
        int len = bytes[i+2];
        // Convert bytes to string
        words.Add(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, i+3, len));
        i += len + 2;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", words.ToArray()));
```

Output:

```
FERREIRA RAMOS MUZI

RICARDO
URY
09031979
MONTEVIDEO/URY
34946682
"           - some non-printable chars here
22072026
```

Looks like some fields will need special parsing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a combination of binary data with strings.  There is a line count.  So this code may help

```
            string input = "\u001f\u0001\u0013FERREIRA RAMOS MUZI\u001f\u0002\0\u001f\u0003\aRICARDO\u001f\u0004\u0003URY\u001f\u0005\b09031979\u001f\u0006\u000eMONTEVIDEO/URY\u001f\a\b34946682\u001f\b\u0004\"\a \u0016\u001f\t\b22072026\u001f\n\0";
            string output = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
            string[] lines = output.Split(new char[] { '\u001f' });
```